# Yii CGridview Pagination renderpartial

Tags: php, jquery, yii, pagination, cgridview

I'm currently rendering 3 CGridviews in my view, all using "renderPartial" and the same php file. This works fine, except for when using pagination, and the user selects another page of results, it moves all the CGridviews to that page (if they can). I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.

I tried this approach [post on Yii forms](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/10254-ajaxlinks-with-renderpartial/page__p__50394__fromsearch__1&#entry50394), and it does fix the pagination of the CGridViews, but breaks my ajax functions and css styles. See below for an image of this occurring.

Here is the CGridView Template

```
<div class="row btn-row">
<h2 class="admin-h1"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
<div class="btn-block-div">
    <button class="btn addOrgBtn" id="<?php echo $title; ?>">Add</button>
</div>
</div>
<?php 
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>$title .'-table',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'selectableRows'=>1,
    'hideHeader'=>true,
    'selectionChanged'=>'viewRoles',
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'header'=>'Name',
            'name'=>'Organization',
        ),
        'Roles',
    ),
));
?>
```

Here are the "RenderPartial" statements inside my view:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom:60px;">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="School-grid">
    <?php echo $this->renderPartial('_roleTable', array('title'=>'School', 'model'=>$model, 'dataProvider'=>$schoolItems)); ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="Classroom-grid">
    <?php echo $this->renderPartial('_roleTable', array('title'=>'Classroom', 'model'=>$model, 'dataProvider'=>$classroomItems)); ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="Shared-grid">
    <?php echo $this->renderPartial('_roleTable', array('title'=>'Shared', 'model'=>$model, 'dataProvider'=>$sharedItems)); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

This is what is currently happening:
[image]

And this is what happens when I add "false, true" to my "RenderPartial" statements like the Yii answer:
[image]

Thanks in advance for the help, I'm really lost on this issue.

***UPDATE***
For reference, I also asked this question [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/54771-cgridview-pagination-renderpartial/page__gopid__251292#entry251292) on the Yii forms, as I find SO has much better response time, but the Yii forms have the concentrated community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was a combination of things.

First off, I needed to set the "updateSelector" attribute of CGridView to a custom page selector for each table.

Secondly, I needed to set the "pageVar" in my "dataProvider" to match the selector.

Here is a static example of this to make it as clear as possible.

DataProvider:

```
new CArrayDataProvider($data, array(
        'sort'=>array(
            'attributes'=>array(
                'Organization',
                'Roles',
            ),
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>10,
            'pageVar'=>'custom-page-selector', //page selector
        ),
    ));
```

CGridView:

```
<?php 
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>$title .'-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'selectableRows'=>1,
    'updateSelector'=>'custom-page-selector', //update selector
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'header'=>'Name',
            'name'=>'Organization',
        ),
        'Roles',
    ),
));
?>
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

if they all react on one of paginations click, it's probably because you named all your grid views with the same name(/id) and it's a matter of conflicted IDs,

that's all

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm setting each CGridview's id when it's created. You can see on the first line in the widget `'id'=>$title .'-table',` The $title variable is the org type (school, class, etc), so each one gets assigned a unique id. I did notice that this id is going on the generated div, not the table itself. I'd assume this is correct as it's a native Yii widget, and they have an "ID" field. I will try explicitly specifying the id on the actual table itself to see if that works.